# How do I create a task in Rails to run one time in the future?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I have a subscription-based site that allows unregistered users to download files if they give me their email. I want the following workflow.

1. User give email address
2. Rails creates a task for 7 days in the future
3. User downloads emailed file
4. If user hasn't signed up in 7 days, send user an email

I need to add #2 and #4. Right now I'm using ActiveJob and Sidekiq to create jobs to send the download email. Is there a way I can create an ActiveJob to run in the future? And will that future job have access to my rails environment to check against my DB?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can enqueue an ActiveJob to be performed in 1 week.  In the job's implementation conditionally send an email if the user hasn't signed up.  Refer to the Rails guides on ActiveJob: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#enqueue-the-job

Example:

```
# Enqueue a job to be performed 1 week from now.
UserConfirmationJob.set(wait: 1.week).perform_later(user)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I need. And I just found this gem for testing the queued jobs: https://github.com/gocardless/rspec-activejob

Comment: Great! If this works for you could you accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Can you do it this way:

1. User gives the email.
2. You allow him to download.
3. Every day you run a script to check that whether the user who gave his email 7 days ago has signed up or not.
4. And you send him an email if he hasn't signed up.

Comment: I'd have to check all my users against the list of downloaders every day. Then, I'd have to add a column in the Users table to check and see if they already received that 7-day email. And it would get more complicated if I wanted to send another after 30 days.